# Opencage package, cannot make batch geocoding work

Tags: r, package, reverse-geocoding

I have a large text file that contains around 2.5M rows, each row contains latitude and longitude points along with a country code. Using the maps package I have been able to successfully reverse geocode all but 57,000 of these entries.

Of those 57,000 remaining most seem to fail because the map used within the maps package is not quite detailed enough and is missing a lot of entries that are right on the coast. Hey, 98%+ return for free on 2.5M isn't half bad!

I then ran those 57,000 through a manual data set of the UK as most of the entries are UK based and I have whittled the no matches down to just 4532.

Now I need to be able to run those remaining cases through an online API and I have selected OpenCage because it gives a generous 2500 daily limit and going forwards once I have these 4352 under control the amount that the data is out by should not exceed more than 100 (the data will be corrected and then it's only the new daily entries that need to be checked).

I've regisered with opencage, have my key and when I make an individual reverse geocode request it all works fine: `GeoTest <- opencage_reverse(latitude = 51.5034070, longitude = -0.1275920, key = ('MyKey'),language = "en", limit = 1, abbrv = TRUE)`

The problem I have is that I cannot for the life of me get this to work with my dataframe.

If I manually make a tibble and run this code it works fine, example: `GeoTest <- tibble(id = 1:4, lat = c(-36.85007, 47.21864, 53.55034, 34.05369), lon = c(174.7706, -1.554136, 10.000654, -118.242767))` `Rev_Geo <- oc_reverse_df(GeoTest, latitude = lat, longitude = lon, key = ('MyKey'),output = "short", language = "en", bind_cols = TRUE )`

But if I try and run the same code against a dataframe, even one converted to a tibble, it refuses to work. I've checked the structure and lat and lon in my DF are numerical. I've tried cutting the DF down to just lat & lon, still no dice.

The error I get is:

> rlang::last_trace()
> <error/vctrs_error_incompatible_type>
> No common type for `..1$op$oc_road_reference`  and `..3$op$oc_road_reference` .
> Backtrace:
> x

1. +-opencage::oc_reverse_df(...)
2. +-opencage:::oc_reverse_df.data.frame(...)
3. | +-tidyr::unnest(results_nest, .data$op, names_repair = "unique")
4. | -tidyr:::unnest.data.frame(results_nest, .data$op, names_repair = "unique")
5. |   -tidyr::unchop(data, !!cols, keep_empty = keep_empty, ptype = ptype)
6. |     -vctrs::vec_rbind(!!!x, .ptype = ptype)
7. +-vctrs:::vec_type2_dispatch(x = x, y = y, x_arg = x_arg, y_arg = y_arg)
8. +-vctrs:::vec_ptype2.tbl_df(x = x, y = y, x_arg = x_arg, y_arg = y_arg)
9. +-vctrs:::vec_ptype2.tbl_df.data.frame(...)
10. +-vctrs:::vec_type2_dispatch(x = x, y = y, x_arg = x_arg, y_arg = y_arg)
11. +-vctrs::vec_ptype2.integer(x = x, y = y, x_arg = x_arg, y_arg = y_arg)
12. -vctrs:::vec_ptype2.integer.default(...)
13. -vctrs::vec_default_ptype2(x, y, x_arg = x_arg, y_arg = y_arg)
14. ```
    \-vctrs::stop_incompatible_type(x, y, x_arg = x_arg, y_arg = y_arg)
    ```
15. ```
      \-vctrs:::stop_incompatible(...)
    ```
16. ```
        \-vctrs:::stop_vctrs(...)
    ```

Comment: Can't help with opencage, but have you thought about using `st_nearest_feature` from the `sf` package?  Might help if points are near coastlines.  https://r-spatial.github.io/sf/reference/st_nearest_feature.html

Comment: @mrhellmann Thanks for the link, I'll certainly take a look. If nothing else it will cut down on the manual data source I currently use in stage 2.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of 'hit head against keyboard moments' it turns out my code was perfect, there seems to be a bug of sorts within the package.

If you clear the cache of opencage using the following code `oc_clear_cache()` it then works. Completely non sensical, but if it ever stops working I just run that code and it starts working again.